# How to display CMake variables from FooConfig.cmake file in CMake GUI?

Tags: c++, cmake

I recently started using modern CMake principles and including Config files in my projects.

Despite that I can use one of my projects, let's say Foo, as a dependency of another one, let's say Bar, I can't see the foo project variables in tools as the CMake GUI when building the project Bar.

However, the paths are correctly found and the dependent project builds correctly. Does any one knows what I miss?

This is an example of the FooConfig.cmake.in file:

```
# - Config file for the foo package
# It defines the following variables
#  Foo_INCLUDE_DIRS - include directories for Foo
#  Foo_LIBRARY_DIRS - library directories for Foo (normally not used!)
#  Foo_LIBRARIES    - libraries to link against

@PACKAGE_INIT@

# Tell the user project where to find our headers and libraries
set_and_check(Foo_INCLUDE_DIRS "@Foo_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR@")
set_and_check(Foo_LIBRARY_DIRS "@Foo_INSTALL_LIBDIR@")

include_directories (${Foo_INCLUDE_DIRS})

include("${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/FooTargets.cmake")

check_required_components("Foo")

set(foo_LIBRARIES Foo)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

CMake GUI shows only variables which are **cached**, that are defined with CACHE option. Since your `FooConfig.cmake` doesn't set the variable as cached, they are not appeared in the GUI.

Actually, there is a little sense to define these variables as CACHE ones: CACHE variables are intended to be **modifiable by a user**, and this is not your case.

Comment: Thank you Tsyvarev! This is exactly what I wanted. Cheers!